# How to get the value of a @Html.HiddenFor field that is in an array and pass the value to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web page with two tabstrips, one nested inside the next in an mvc 5 application. I am using a hidden field to hold the index of the first tabstrip whenever the model is passed back to the controller like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.tab1Index)
```

and I get the value into the tabstrip like this:

```
tabstrip.select(@Model.tab1Index)
```

All this works fine. I want to do the same thing with the nested tabstrip. However, this is not working.
I use this for the hidden element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.tabstrip1[i].tab2Index
```

and for the tabstrip, I don't know how to get this part working.

```
tabstrip2.select(@Model.tabstrip1[i].tab2Index)
```

How can I get the correct hidden element value and pass it to the tabstrip?

Comment: One question, is tabstrip2.select a JavaScript/Jquery code?

Comment: tabstrip2 is actually a kendo ui widget.

Comment: provide jsfiddle link